Zipper Shading Issue

Does anyone know why the shading occurs on the zipper puller and how to fix it?
I did the texture in Substance painter, after baking, the diagonal marks appeared. Its still there when I imported the textures into blender.
Thank you!

Probably poor underlying topology. - It doesn't look as if that was created in Blender judging by all the triangles and ngons.
